# How to extract a string of mixed number and text, and get the average numbers?

Tags: python, regex, string, dataframe

I have a column in my data frame that contains strings of numbers and text such as:

```
0    200 to 500 people
1    1 to 5 people
2    5000 people and over
3    2000 to 3000 people
```

I want to convert each of these strings into one number. For those that have a range, we can consider the average of the range and for those that only contain one number, we can extract the same number. so my result should be as:

```
0 350
1 3
2 5000
3 2500
```

I would appreciate it if you give me a hint of how to do that. I know how to use regex to get the numbers but here I don't know exactly how to average numbers for rows containing two numbers and at the same time get the only number for those rows containing one number.

Comment: This requires natural language processing, which, to say the least, is challenging. For example, how is the code to distinguish between `"5000 people and over"` and `"5000 people and over 6000 cows"`? What about `"2000 to over 3000 people"`? Also, it seems open-ended as to the number of such phrases. Do you need to account for `"At most 3000 people"`? What about phrases that are grammatically incorrect, such as `"5000 people and over"`? I think you are asking too much of code.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous as to whether you only care about numbers `\d+`, specific range or both? Is it guaranteed to only contain a number or a range? As @CarySwoveland mentioned your input seems arbitrary, complicated and requires more than some lines of code to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

assume the string values are stored in the `s` column,

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'s': '200 to 500 people'}, {'s': '1 to 5 people'}, {'s': '5000 people and over'}, {'s': '2000 to 3000 people'}, {"s": "some text"}])
>>> df.head()
                      s
0     200 to 500 people
1         1 to 5 people
2  5000 people and over
3   2000 to 3000 people
4             some text
```

then:

```py
>>> df["values"] = df["s"].str.extractall(r"(\d+)").astype(int).groupby(level=0).mean()
>>> df.head()
                      s  values
0     200 to 500 people   350.0
1         1 to 5 people     3.0
2  5000 people and over  5000.0
3   2000 to 3000 people  2500.0
4             some text     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. I have a minor problem. In some of the rows, I have only text and no number. This method deletes those rows which is fine. however, how to keep the rest of the columns corresponding to the left rows?

Comment: help-ukraine-now, yes!

Comment: see the updated answer, isn't it what you expect? @pymn